# Can "(input * X) mod Y" with N iterations be computed in less than N operations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I think a simple question but here it goes (and sorry for my lack of math notation skills):

Given input I, a fixed factor X and fixed modulo Y and N iterations, does the process need to be performed consecutively in N steps, or can it be sped up?

```
I=12345
X=655573
Y=54321
for N=0; N < 10000; N++ {
    I=(I*Y)%X
}
```

Comment: @kelalaka predictable would be that there is no faster way to compute the end result other than running serial.

Comment: Is there any secret on the input? Otherwise, SEJPM's answer should satisfy you.

Comment: @kelaka there are not any secrets(except the output of course), the idea is to have a function that just uses multiplication (and maybe addition) and mod (no comparisons/if's) to have an unpredictable outcome when run over a large amount of iterations, like hashing hashes for N times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are not any secrets(except the output of course), the idea is to have a function that just uses multiplication (and maybe addition) and mod (no comparisons/if's) to have an unpredictable outcome when run over a large amount of iterations, like hashing hashes for N times

If you are ok with there being "one secret" (although you do not need to store it at all), there is a simple construction of this form (which is *nearly* the one you already have).

> Let $N = pq$ be an RSA pseudo-prime. Define the function:
> $$ f^0(m) = m\bmod N,\quad f^{i+1}(m) = (f^i(m))^2\bmod N$$

Then it is hypothesized that this function is inherently sequential (and therefore has your desired "unpredictable outcome"), provided that factoring N is difficult. Note that this is just a *conjecture* --- factoring N could be difficult, and this function could be parallelizable (but the problem has been open for a few decades).

I will write your function as:
$$g^0(m) = m\bmod N,\quad g^{i+1}(m) = Yg^i(m)\bmod N$$

The function $f$ differs from your function $g$ in two important ways.

1. It "squares" at each step (and therefore $f^i(m) = m^{2^i}\bmod N$), instead of multiplying by $Y$ (which yields $g^i(m) = mY^i\bmod N$).
2. It requires $N = pq$ to be large enough that RSA is hard (say 2048 bits minimum, maybe 4096 though).

Both of these seem important to change:

1. The first allows a pre-processing attack (compute the table $g^{2^i}(1)$ for $i\in [\log N]$, then you can compute $g^j(m) = m\prod_{i\in[\log N]}g^{b_i2^i}(1)$, where $b_i$ is the binary decomposition of $j$). This can clearly be parallelized.
2. If $N$ is too small, you can factor it to find $p, q$, then compute $g^i(m) = mY^i\bmod N = mY^{i\bmod (p-1)(q-1)}\bmod N$, which you can then compute efficiently.

The "one secret" mentioned here is the factorization $N = pq$.

Comment: So just to ask: if I do `I=((I*Y)*(I*Y))%X` in my loop instead it should become unpredictable is what you are saying? (Given the numbers and modulo are large enough?)

Comment: It likely will, but the multiplication by $Y$ is unnecessary. If you make your inner loop `I = I*I %  X`, it will become precisely the function for which parallization is hypothesized to be hard. I would recommend you not refer to this as being "unpredictable" though, and instead call it "hard to parallelize" or "inherently sequential".

Comment: I don't not believe the multiplication by $Y$ hurts things at all, but I also do not believe it helps things at all. It likely just makes your computation of the function slightly slower, but a "smart adversary" could avoid this computational cost by computing your function in a slightly different way.

Comment: I see, thank you, the idea was to use this method within the homomorphic domain as 'inherently sequential'. I*I % X actually makes it much easier in that regard. However doing unlimited multiplications homomorphically still seems a somewhat unresolved issue, but that might be another question ;)

Comment: @ovanwijk You can do unlimited multiplications via bootstrapping, but this of course incurs a decent amount of computational overhead. These kinds of constructions have become popular lately due to applications in blockchain related things (the relevant term to search is "Verifiable Delay Functions"). I don't currently see any constructions from lattices, but generically you could look through known constructions and see if any are better suited for homomorphic computation.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm is computing $$I'=I\cdot Y^N\bmod X$$. Using a [standard square and multiply algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) you need at most $\lceil 2\log_2(N)\rceil+1$ modular multiplications to compute $I'$.  This is about 33 multiplications for the given example of $N=10,000$ which probably counts as this algorithm being "predictable".

Comment: In addition, if you know the factorization of $X$ (which includes the case that $X$ is prime), then you can process large values of $N$ by computing $N \bmod \phi(N)$, and using that as the exponent; that means you never need to do more than $O(\log X)$ modular multiplications, no matter how large $N$ is...

Comment: Yes, by [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Comment: Minor fix to @poncho's remark: the reduced exponent is computed as $N\bmod\phi(X)$. Some improvements: We can reduce that exponent to $N\bmod\lambda(X)$ (where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)), or better [use the CRT as in RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) to speed-up the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can quite easily evaluate the n-th number in the sequence, for arbitrary large n.

That can be an advantage if all you want is calculate random numbers quickly, fir example for simulations, where the numbers don’t need any cryptographic properties. You can also use vector units to calculate multiple numbers in parallel.

On this site it would be considered a disadvantage though.